# Error response from daemon: rpc error:

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

i am tryng to join docker to a swarm in a raspberry pi cluster. but it fails to connect to the swarm.

i have run the command on a fresh install of raspbian and docker.

i get the error:

```
sudo docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-21cr61rgp0th4sr8g8jxdm8cmd2jyvdzdnjg8qjrsrve3887sy-bs1rhj7nru96982kv0juay2ed 192.168.1.2:2377
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable
```

i cannot figure out what could be causing this. does anyone know what could be causing this? any help is appreciated.

Comment: port open on the manager?

Comment: Are you able to telnet to 192.168.1.2:2377?

Comment: hi. thanks. it seemed to be that the server couldnt connect.